# Resetting a rolling sum

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I am trying to create a rolling stock count from the quantity. The count should reset everytime there is a real stock count (TypeOfMovement = 3). This should work on each ArticleNo and be grouped by date.

I can get a running stock count (lines <123 in image) and then take the real stock count when TypeOfMovement = 3 (Line 123 of image), but the count doesn't reset, it continues from before the real stock count (ResetRunningTotal in line124 should be 6293).

The solution should run in SSMS. Alternatively a python solution could be run.

My query so far is:

```
WITH a
AS
(SELECT
        DateOfMovement, Quantity, ArticleNo, TypeOfChange,
        CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange = 3 Then 0
        ELSE Quantity
        END AS RunningTotal
    FROM Stock_Table
    Group by DateOfMovement, Quantity, ArticleNo, TypeOfChange)
SELECT
    *
    ,CASE
        WHEN TypeOfChange= 3 THEN Quantity   
        ELSE Sum(Quantity) OVER(ORDER BY ArticleNo, DateOfMovement)
    END AS ResetRunningTotal
FROM a
WHEre ArticleNo = 9410
group by DateOfMovement, ArticleNo, Quantity, TypeOfChange, RunningTotal
order by DateOfMovement asc
```

Image of results table is..

[image: Image of result]

Comment: You're using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation function. So the value of `RunningTotal` comes from a random row in the group.

Comment: I probably should have cleaned that section out  as the column i create of RunningTotal isnt helping me at all right now - that part has got a bit messy as I have been trying different things out. The ResetRunningTotal is close to what i want if it would reset the rolling sum (e.g. after line 123)

Comment: What database? different DBMS engines implement various parts of the SQL language differently especially when it comes to Aggregate and Analytic functions.

Comment: It is in SSMS and would be using T-SQL

Comment: SSMS is mostly irrelevant, it's just a query tool.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you want running totals for each `ArticleNo` ordered by `DateOfMovement` that reset whenever you encounter a `TypeOfChange` value of 3.

To do this you need to create a grouping_id (`Grp`) for each running total.  You can do this with a CTE that calculates group ids, then do the running totals with the CTE results:

```
with Groups as (
select st.*
     , sum(case TypeOfChange when 3 then 1 else 0 end)
       over (partition by ArticleNo order by DateOfMovement) Grp
  from Stock_Table st
)
select Groups.*
     , sum(Quantity) over (partition by ArticleNo, Grp order by DateOfMovement) RunningTotal
  from Groups
 order by ArticleNo, dateofmovement
```